# Configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'fallback'. These properties are valid:

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf, craco

I got this error in my react project.

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

```
- configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'fallback'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, concord?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
   -> Options for the resolver
```

I have try to build react pdf for my project. I have used craco for resolving errors caused by re

```json
    var webpack = require("webpack");

    module.exports = {
      webpack: {
        configure: {
          resolve: {
            fallback: {
              process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
              zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
              stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
              util: require.resolve("util"),
              buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
              asset: require.resolve("assert"),
            },
          },
          plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
              Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
              process: "process/browser",
            }),
          ],
        },
      },
    };
```

act pdf. Here is my code.

Comment: Please share your package.json - which webpack version are you running?

Comment: Thanks for replaying my question. I have resolved this issue by updating react-scripts version since it was used older version.